# export 'DarkTheme' (imported as 'DarkTheme') was not found in 'react-native-paper'

Tags: react-native

I have been using this package https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator

```
npm install @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs react-native-paper react-native-vector-icons
```

but after installing this, i keep getting this warning

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs/lib/module/views/MaterialBottomTabView.js:109:51
export 'DarkTheme' (imported as 'DarkTheme') was not found in 'react-native-paper'
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Have you fixed the issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

As it is just a warning, and not an issue as it used to be ([issue here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/11219)), you can just ignore it.

Another option is to use BottomNavigation from [React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/BottomNavigation/) as mentioned in [BottomNavigation with React Navigation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/bottom-navigation/) guide.

In my case, it did not change the look of navigation, but removed warnings as the package `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` was not used.